# HTML form submit button doesn't sent data form

Tags: c#, html, forms

I use DNN and C#. I've got a form with a lot of input and select HTML tag. At the end of form there is a . When I click on it, the page is reload but when I try catch data of form (with Request.Form['formName'] or Request['form']) I've got only empty field (and if I check the value of IsPostback, it's always false). But in the form tag there is value.

FILE View.ascx

```
    <div class="row">
         <div class="col-sm-2">&nbsp;</div>
         <div class="col-sm-4">
              <label for="formCodiceCanile">Codice Canile</label>
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-4">
             <input type="text" name="formCodiceCanile" ID="formCodiceCanile" value="<%=InfoScheda.CodiceCanile %>" />
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-2">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>

    OTHER FIELD (such as input text, select and radio button)

   <input type="submit" name="formRegistraScheda" id="formRegistraScheda" value="Registra scheda" />
```

I know that I can use  (and if I use it, there isn't problem because catch the value in the asp:Textbox it's a joke) but in this case I can't use them.

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: your html button should be an asp.net button control

Comment: @prospector : Thank you for your help. I try <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Registra scheda" ID="formRegistraScheda"  OnClick="formRegistraScheda_Click"/> (without OnClick attribute too) but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PROBLEM SOLVED: the button doesn't do the POST because I use a field's form in the URL to observe the page status. Now I remove this control and I use the IsPostback native variable of C# and the form work!